# How can I send a data from WCF host to connected client?

Tags: wcf, service, client, host

I want to send a data from WCF host (not service proxy) to the connected client with the service.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Either using a Duplex channel as Jacob points out, or then you need to create a separate ServiceHost in each of your applications and get them to call each other; in one case, machine A is the client and calls machine B, and then the roles are reversed and machine B is making a call back to the service host on machine A.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create a *Duplex* service.  See this article for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Here's an example:

```
[ServiceContract(
    SessionMode=SessionMode.Required,
    CallbackContract=typeof(INotificationServiceCallback))]
public interface INotificationService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Connect();
}

public interface INotificationServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void SendNotification(string notification);
}

public class NotificationService : INotificationService
{
    public static List<INotificationServiceCallback> Clients = 
        new List<INotificationServiceCallback>();

    public void Connect()
    {
        Clients.Add(
            OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ICalculatorDuplexCallback>());
    }
}

public class Notifier
{
    void HandleReceivedNotification(string notification)
    {
        foreach (var client in NotificationService.Clients)
        {
            client.SendNotification(notification);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but I have knwon Duplex service can send a data from service proxy to client. I want to from host not proxy.

Comment: The data comes from the host ultimately.  Are you asking for the ability for a WCF host to initiate a call to a client?

Comment: yes, I want that WCF host a call, so send a data to connected client. this is different from callback. callback is for from service proxy to client.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what a "callback" is in WCF terminology.  You already mentioned you only want to send data to a connected client.  WCF will allow the service to call methods in the client's callback contract at any time.

Comment: I have known callback means just 'from service' that service proxy.

Comment: If possible, please show me the sample code that send a data from host to client.

Comment: You need to use the service proxy on the client to connect to the server.  How else will you have a "connected client" for the server to talk to?

Comment: Hmm.. sorry, I did not write my question exactly. For example, An winform host a service, and the other winform client connect to the service. In this, a winform host need to send a data to connected winform client program. How can I(winform host) do this..?

Comment: My example still works for that scenario.  The code for Winform A has a service proxy to the service hosted on Winform B.  Winform A calls Winform B.  Winform B obtains a client callback object for Winform A.  Winform B can now call Winform A.

Comment: I am confused now for your last comment. you mean Winform B is a host program? If so, "Winform B obtains a client callback object for Winform A" is wrong to me. I think 'service proxy' that created when winform A connected, obtains a callback object. not host program Winform B.. am I wrong?

Comment: If possible, please full project using the above your sample code. If you can do that, I am very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Winform B is the host.  In order for Winform B to call clients (Winform A), the clients must connect so that the host can obtain the "callback" proxy.

Comment: So, In host code, how can I access the callback? In the above code, how can the host access the Clients that type of List<INotificationServiceCallback> ?

Comment: My sample `Connect` method shows how to access the callback.  The `Notifier` class was meant to illustrate how code in the host application could broadcast messages to all clients of the service.

Comment: Do you mean, In host program code, create instance that type of 'Notifier' and call HandleReceivedNotification method?

Comment: I don't know what triggers the logic where you want the host to call the clients; you haven't said what your application does.  The important part is to store a callback reference for a client, then later call methods in the callback.